# How to render particular attributes of an object using devise?

Tags: authentication, attributes, devise, render, rabl

I am using devise gem, everything works great, but the problem is after the login the entire user object is rendered. So if I send a json request to login it will return everything that the user object holds, I was able to limit to particular attributes using a rabl file during registration. What I did was just created a create.rabl in the views/devise/registration. But the same thing is not working for login. So how can i limit the resource attributes using devise.

Comment: I've accomplished this by using a create.rabl in devise/sessions/ on devise 2.0.4, which version of devise are you using?

Answer (score 0):

After login, devise redirects, probably to user#show, so create a view file `views/users/show.json.rabl` that contains the attributes you want to return, for example,

```
object @users

attributes :id, :name, :email
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl